# How in wordpress bootstrap tab add active class to items and contents

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have function below it is work without any problem only don't add the `active` class in `nav-tabs li` and `tab-content div` during click on items.

problem in my code: only don't add class to these to lines below

```
$item_output .= '<li>';
$item_output .= '<div class="tab-pane" id="'.$YPE_category->slug.'">';
```

**Info:** When i use the same function (But only remove the `&$item_output` argument and replace `$item_output` variable to `echo`) it is work and add `active` class to items and contents without any problem. Means when i use `$item_output` instead of `echo` not add `active` class!

How i can add `active` class directly during click on items or show contents when i click on items? i think may do this by jQuery but i can't do it?

```
function YPE_bstab(&$item_output, $item) {
    $YPE_categories = get_terms('category', array(
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'number'  => $item->items_num,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'hide_empty' => 1
    ));
    $item_output .= '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">';
        foreach ($YPE_categories as $YPE_category) {
            $item_output .= '<li>';
                $item_output .= '<a href="#'.$YPE_category->slug.'" data-toggle="tab">'.$YPE_category->name.'</a>';
            $item_output .= '</li>';
        }
    $item_output .= '</ul>';
    $item_output .= '<div class="tab-content">';
    foreach ($YPE_categories as $YPE_category) {
        $item_output .= '<div class="tab-pane" id="'.$YPE_category->slug.'">';
            $YPE_Query = array('posts_per_page' => $item->items_num,'category_name'  => $YPE_category->slug);
            $YPE_cat_query = new WP_Query($YPE_Query);
            while ($YPE_cat_query->have_posts()) {
                $YPE_cat_query->the_post();
                $item_output .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID()).'</a>';
                $item_output .= '<p><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></p>';
            }
            wp_reset_query();
        $item_output .= '</div>';
    }
    $item_output .= '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use javascript code it is better way to show `active` class

First: remove `data-toggle="tab"`.

Second: ad this `id` to `li` in this line `$item_output .= '<li>';` like this `$item_output .= '<li id="myTabs">';`

Third: add this javascript code under your code or in anu js file within your theme or script.

```
$('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).tab('show')
})
```

Comment: it is perfect solution thank you worked perfectly with me